# Device on local network ARP poisoning

Tags: networking, arp

I've been dealing with this problem for a while. A device attached to my router with "Wistron Neweb Corporation" as its hostname ARP poisons the network every time it manages to get attached. At the time of writing, it's holding 3 addresses; here's the relevant output from `arp -a` on my Windows desktop.

```
192.168.50.39         60-02-b4-80-c3-70     dynamic
192.168.50.104        60-02-b4-80-c3-70     dynamic
192.168.50.122        60-02-b4-80-c3-70     dynamic
```

`192.168.50.104` is what my router shows for this device's assigned address. The other two don't belong to it at all, and one of them is my desktop. Wireshark also shows it spoofing other addresses that don't show up in `arp`, and strangely enough, it keeps sending UDP packets to `192.168.50.255`, which is out of my current allowed address range (it runs from `.2 - .254` right now).

My original solution was to add it to the MAC filter on my router, which worked for a few months, but today it managed to connect despite being banned from the network.  My main concerns here are:

- How do I get the device to drop its addresses or force it off the network?
- Is this a security issue I should be worried about?

Comment: I'm no networking expert and don't claim to be one, so I'd imagine there may be a need for more context. Feel free to ask.

Comment: BTW,  192.168.50.255 is the broadcast address for 192.168.50.0/24.

Comment: Those aren't addresses that "the box thinks that it has". Those are values that the arp cache thinks that it has had. Arp timeout should be around 30 seconds (what version of Windows?), so the arp cache indicates that the TV has had 3 addresses in the last 2 minutes, not that it is holding onto 3 addresses. What is providing dhcp? Router? some dhcp servers are incompatible with some dhcp clients.

Comment: Yes, the router is providing DHCP. I already cleared my ARP cache, and Wireshark confirms that the box is holding on to multiple addresses. All the traffic from these addresses is being sent twice - once by the actual device associated with the address, once from the box. It's completely messing up address resolution network-wide for multiple computers.

Comment: [Here's a little bit](https://i.imgur.com/jN7gH4G.png) of the Wireshark capture. You can see the chaos this box is causing.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a wireless network, make sure you're using a secure encryption standard like WPA2 or later, and change the password. Do not use WEP under any circumstances. Change the admin password to the router too, while you're at it.

If you're running a wired network, there will only be so many places it can be connected. Check them, and when you find this device, unplug it.

Comment: I already have the router set to WPA2 with AES. Traced it back to the set top box in my living room. Obviously that doesn't constitute a security issue since it's my own device, so something's up with its network settings. I can't imagine why in God's name that would cause it to start ARP poisoning though.

Comment: Going back through the .pcapng I saved, I counted 6 different addresses that the box thinks it has. 5 of those obviously don't belong to it. Even giving it a static IP on the router doesn't work; no matter what I do, the box doesn't listen. Cheap Taiwanese networking hardware gives me a headache.

Comment: Perhaps it's not implementing DHCP properly - it wouldn't be the first device to muck that up. You could try setting a static IP address on the set-top box and excluding that address from the DHCP range on the router.